# How do you utilize the flipview and make a "selection" by tapping or clicking the screen?

Tags: xaml, user-interface, windows-8, winrt-xaml

In Win 8, the flipview control is a great control to browse the collection.  But how or what is the best way to make a "selection" with a tap or a mouse click?  I can always put a button outside of the flip view, but that's not the touch experience that everyone of a tablet would expect.

can someone give some example code (XAML/C#) of how to setup a flipview control with a selection of some sort that would navigate to a totally different page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote some sample code that works, if I'm understanding the question correctly.  I am able to swipe through the FlipView and tap the individual item:

```
<FlipView Tapped="FlipView_Tapped_1">
    <Image Source="Images/Apple.jpg" />
    <Image Source="Images/Orange.jpg" />
    <Image Source="Images/Banana.jpg" />
</FlipView>
```

And then

```
private YourTypeHere SelectedItem;
private void FlipView_Tapped_1(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.SelectedItem = (sender as FlipView).SelectedItem;
}
```

You might not want to set a field, but you get the idea. Hopefully, you will be setting something in your view model. From there you can nav away or anything you need. A FlipView inherits from ItemsControl just like every other XAML repeater. So you can treat it exactly the same. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx

Comment: +1 The Tapped event also handles Mouse actions, so that's nice!

Comment: it appears the tapped event is also fired if you tap/click the navigation arrows to advance to the next item in the flipview...

this is okay to handle in the code-behind since I can filter out the event by inspecting the OriginalSource and make sure it's the image... 

but I can't seem to find a way to do this if I'm using behaviors to trigger a command on tapped, since the navigation arrow triggers it but doesn't have the context of the tapped item. any ideas?